# Chrome + JQuery Ajax POST request + base64 encoded string = FAIL

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post, base64

I have to send some base64 encoded (host-specific) data via JQuery to our web server, for serial number generation.
All the scripts are minimized, so I can keep the entire logic + the info I'm sending away from "curious" customers. It's not 100% safe, but still it offers some "protection".

Now back to my problem: the entire thing works well in all the browsers (IE6+, FF, Opera and Safari?, at least it worked the last time I've checked it), but not newer versions of Chrome.
The base64-encoded parameter is blank.. I've tried to alert the value I'm sending (data parameter of JQuery's ajax request) and it's OK. Some how Chrome detects base64 string and trims it.

Comment: You say the parameter is blank yet it has a value you can see when you alert it... how did you determine it's blank?

Comment: @deed02392 Oh yeah.. You are right, I had to add those details too: so basically I tried to check it in Firebug Lite (javascript console) and inside the PHP script that receives the bas64 string value. In both cases that particular POST variable is blank.

Comment: Anyway I "solved" the problem just by mirroring my base64 string before sending it in javascript and then I mirror it back in PHP.
Still I curious what is the real solution.